# Click on element inside a button not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, html

It works as it supposed to in Chrome but not in Firefox.

This is my button element:

```
<button class="btn btn-default">some text <i>remove</i> </button>
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
$('button').not('i').click(function(){ alert('button was clicked') });

$('button i').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('i was clicked');   `
});
```

How can I attach click event listener to the `<i>` tag in jQuery without triggering parent? I'm using bootstrap buttons.

In CSS I have `position: relative;` for the `<button>`, and `position: absolute;` for the `<i>`

Comment: This is bad practice, e.g. how would you target the `<i>` with keyboard (tabbing)? Both elements should be sibling `<button>s` and you can (un)style those 2 buttons and wrap them in a container you can style differently. For example(not saying you should use bootstrap): https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/button-group/

Comment: i love when there is a problem to solve, and instead solving it someone sais dont do it this way. How do you know Rene what circumstances im using this ? Why the hell would i wrap them in this or that. Dont answer if you cant

Comment: If you ask for help, don't be rude and reject criticism. What Rene is saying are valid points and if you do take them into consideration or not it's up to you. You come here to learn or not - it's up to you, but you should be grateful that someone is taking their time to try and 'educate' you and others who might be looking for answers. Seeing the answers and your response gives the impression that your question could be improved.

Comment: Im grateful if someone is solving the problem i asked. But he is the one who is criticising me, with no point. If i asked hey guys is this a good way to approach, than i very welcome the answers

Comment: What if his points will fix your problem? Also he didn't answer anything. This is what the comments section is for. For discussions not answers. You need to remember that browsers are implemented differently. Maybe Firefox does not support `i` elements inside buttons? Or maybe it doesn't support `i` elements at all (depending on your browser version of course). Following good/better practices will minimize the amount of problems you run into.

Comment: I think it does, but even if i rename the tag to span, is still not fires

Comment: Sure, assumption is the mother of all * ups. But "<i>remove</i>" seems like you want a "remove" action on the `<i>` specifically. But either way you want a sub actionable element which is bad practice in every circumstance I can think of. I will answer your question if you can convince me with a real valid circumstance ;-)

Comment: so if you assume something, but it is just an assumption, why dont you answer the question and use the sentence 'by the way if...' no it is not removing im actually reseting some content inside the button. Real valid circumstance can be a really really complicated thing, asking a specific question in a more simplified form is just understandable, otherwise where would you draw the line for a button press problem posting the whole project, or just that particular script, or just the function ? come on

Comment: I have just good intentions pointing out that it's bad practice. It might come over as blunt/offensive, which is because comments cannot be long, or shortsighted which I can guarantee is not the case. It's a usability issue I know enough about.
"no it is not removing im actually reseting some content inside the button", with that in mind I can tell you **without assumptions** a different approach is better.

Comment: And why I would not just answer the question? Because I think it's a too bad scenario I would not want anyone to ever implement until browsers (unlikely) cope with nested action elements in a usable way. "BTW if..." is not enough to prevent people from doing the bad thing and I rather just steer people into the right direction right away. (and there is an actual exception that sort of works, anchors in labels but I would suggest to use it sparingly)

Comment: Your code `$('button').not('i').click(function(){ alert('button was clicked') });` makes no sense, because a `button` element cannot also be an `i` element.

Answer (score 0):

Is it this what you want,hope this code helps you

```js
$("i").click(function(){
alert("I gets clicked ");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default">some text <i>remove</i> </button>
```

Comment: Working in chrome, but not in firefox. im using firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Use only `e.stopPropagation();` and try it

```js
$('button').click(function(){ alert('button was clicked') });

$('button i').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('i was clicked'); 
})
```

```css
button{
  position:relative;
}
button i{
  position:absolute;
  left:100px;
  top:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default">some text <i>remove</i> </button>
```

Comment: I know it supposed to work, but it does not. Does even the snippet work for you ? Because for me it is not triggering the click on i tag !!

Comment: Oh I got it know. It is working in Chrome, but not in Firefox. I need to solution for firefox

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```js
$("i").click(function(){
alert("I gets clicked ");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-default">some text <i>remove</i> </a>
```

Comment: Oh Yes IT IS. The parent MUST not be  <button> tag in firefox to be able to handle listener of its children.

Comment: yes , if you use button than whole html with in button tag can be read as a button event. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to replace the parent's BUTTON tag to something else, otherwise firefox wont handle the children's event listener. Thanks the answers by the way

Comment: In general, If you have a button element it is because you want to be able to click it. If you want to only get clicks on an element inside it (not recommended) then using a different element and styling it is the right solution.